# What will be the value(s) of $a$ for wich limit is defined?

Tags: calculus, limits

What I am getting is this form. 
Somehow the answer is $a=arctan(2)$ and the limit evaluates to $-1/10$ can someone show how?

$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}} \, \frac{\tan ^{-1}(\sin (x)+1)-a}{\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2}=\left(\tan ^{-1}(2)-a\right) \infty$

Comment: Your Question, as it is, doesn't make much sense. The limit you get is infinity, unless a is a function depending on x. Why? The numerator is just $arctan(2)-a$ which is some constant, granted $a \neq arctan(2)$ and the denominator goes to 0 as x goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. In the case that $a=arctan(2)$, you can use L'hospital to evaluate your limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x) = 1$.
Thus, by composition, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan(\sin(x)+1) = \arctan(2)$.

We can easily see that the limit in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ of the denominator is $0$, so the function admits a limit only if the limit of the numerator is also $0$, that happens only if $a=\arctan(2)$

Let us now see if this limit exists, and compute it.
For this, we will use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Let us denote by $$f(x) = \arctan(\sin(x)+1) \text{ and } g(x) = \left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2$$
Then 
$$ f'(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{1+(\sin(x)^2+1)} \text{ and } g'(x) = 2\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$
Thus, by L'Hôpital's rule, 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\arctan(\sin(x)+1)}{\left(x-\frac{pi}{2}\right)^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x)}{2\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)(1+\sin(x)^2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x)}{10\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$
because $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} 1+\sin(x)^2 = 5$.
By applying once again L'Hôpital's rule, we get that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x)}{10\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{-\sin(x)}{10}=-\frac{1}{10}$$
This gives us the wanted results.